# Can Ruby on Rails 3 work with MySQL on Windows 7?

Tags: mysql, postgresql, windows-7, ruby-on-rails-3, mysql2

I try to install Rails 3 on Windows 7, and

```
rails new someapp -d mysql
cd someapp
bundle install
```

will fail at mysql2

so, there is no way to use MySQL but to stick with SQLite3.  But I tried

```
rails new app_postgres -d postgresql
cd app_postgres
bundle install
```

and it all worked.

Does that mean perhaps Rails team favor Postgresql slightly more than MySQL?  Is there actually a way to make Rails 3 use the old mysql gems instead so that it can work on Windows or can you somehow make it work, such as by downloading the free Visual Studio and compile mysql2 ourselves?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Working on it](http://github.com/brianmario/mysql2/issues#issue/8)
For now you can use sqlite for development.

Comment: can we use any old mysql gem or driver for now and use MySQL?

Comment: then maybe... Rails on Windows can default to mysql gem initially... just so that it runs at least...

Answer (score 1):

You can now install mysql2 gem on windows7 which is working fine with Rails3. 
To install, follow the steps given in post - http://rorguide.blogspot.com/2011/03/installing-mysql2-gem-on-ruby-192-and.html